# datepicker-options being ignored for bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

From http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/top it says I can pass all my options in a json file but for some reason I can not get it to work. I have been playing with the plunkr the page provides for reference.

http://plnkr.co/edit/7Sa89G5R17erJrVRxypl?p=preview

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    showWeeks: false,
    formatDayTitle: 'MMMM yyyy',
    formatDay: 'd',
    isDisabledMonths: false,
    showButtonBar: false
};
```

In my markup I have

```
 <uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" datepicker-options="dateOptions" min-date="minDate" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></uib-datepicker>
```

But the datepicker is still showing the weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datepicker-options` are only applicable to popups

I would suggest something like:

```
<uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" show-weeks=false  ....
```

Comment: Oh, the wording was confusing to me. Thanks!